# jquery timepicker and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass time values ​​to timepicker. I take time from the database using ajax.
when i pass the values ​​from the database to the parameter disableTimeRanges ,

```
$(function() {
        $("#id_time_visit").timepicker({
             timeFormat: 'H:i',
             minTime: '8', 
             maxTime: '19',
             step: 60,
             disableTimeRanges: []
        });
    });
    $('.pole').change('input', function() {
     var datetime = $(this).val();//I get the value from the form field
       $.ajax({
       url: '/your-url/',
       type: 'get', 
       data: {'datetime': datetime},
        success: function(e){
             console.log(e)
             var time=e;
             $("#id_time_visit").timepicker({
                 timeFormat: 'H:i',
                 minTime: '8', 
                 maxTime: '19',
                 step: 60,
                 disableTimeRanges: time
             });
        },
        error: function(e){
             console.log(e);
        }
    })
```

time becomes unavailable, but when I select another day, which has a different time, then the time for that day becomes inaccessible only if I reload the page. How to make time update when changing days without rebooting

Comment: "When changing days" that's an event we should imagine :) How does that part of the code looks like? which event calls what?

Comment: @bilel i'm update question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a timepicker in this case, we update only the specific targeted option.
The array in this code is meant to simulate your Ajax call.

```js
let disRange = [
    [
        "11.00 am",
        "16.00 am"
    ]
 ];
$(function() {
        $("#id_time_visit").timepicker({
             timeFormat: 'H:i',
             minTime: '8', 
             maxTime: '19',
             step: 60,
             disableTimeRanges: []
        });
        $('#id_time_visit').timepicker('option', 'disableTimeRanges', disRange);   
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.10.0/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>


<input id="id_time_visit" type="text">
```

P.S:If it's not working, please share your other part of code where you using events on (calendar) Days inputs...

Comment: how to pass your values ​​with ajax to disRange?

Comment: if your response data (time) has the same array format, you just replace it after [var time=e;] . But still you didn't explain the part of dates... I understand you send datetime to get time from the database or API but what's getting visually inaccessible? You mean the input targeted by timepicker() ? If my guess is true, it means it's not being reinitialized properly... You can try my code in your ajax first

Comment: it's really working thanks.does not work if there is no time from the database, more precisely, the past time remains inaccessible, but with this everything is clear. Naado should write if when there is no time and pass an empty array there. Am I right?

Comment: You can validate  your ajax response then... and put my code in a condition ! So nothing changes when the response is empty. Or display an error to tell ... It's up to you :) You are welcome